# Observe all changes to an ember object with setPath

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In emberJS, I have a model with an object property called style. I can set it's properties using `test.setPath('style.a')`. I am trying to observe the style object but my observe callback is not firing.

You can see the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kTsrX/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This basic misunderstanding of how Ember observers work is a common mistake. In your example, you have the following in your view `test`:

```
...

style : Ember.Object.create({
    a:4,
    b:2
}),
setStyle : function(key, val){
    var style = this.get('style');
    style[key] = val;
    this.set('style', style);        
},

...
```

The `test.style` property is pointing to an `Ember.Object` and `test.setStyle()` is changing the value of a given property on that `Ember.Object`. A common mistake is thinking that resetting a property to the same object will call any observer on it as you're doing with this line: `this.set('style', style)`. Well that's not how Ember observers work. Observers in Ember are fired automatically when the actual value of a property has changed. Setting the `style` property to itself doesn't change the object `style` is pointing to, thus it doesn't change the value of the property (actually that code does nothing at all). In this case it looks like you need to tell Ember manually that the `style` property has changed. You can do that by calling `notifyPropertyChange()`.

Look at the following modified code for `setStyle`:

```
setStyle : function(key, val){
    var style = this.get('style');
    style.set(key, val); // You should always use `.get()` and `.set()`

    this.notifyPropertyChange('style');
}
```

This will cause your observer to fire.